# Import Django Models Into PyCharm's Python Console

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I am following the Django tutorial and using PyCharm. I am trying to import `Question` and `Choice` from models.py INTO the PyCharm "Python Console". I have `__init__.py` files located in top-level mysite, lower-level mysite, and in polls directory.

I am using a virtual environment and it is activated in the PyCharm Python Console.

```
C:\Users\Jarad\PycharmProjects\OfficialDjangoTutorial\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 51164 51165
PyDev console: starting.

import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\Jarad\\PycharmProjects\\OfficialDjangoTutorial', 'C:/Users/Jarad/PycharmProjects/OfficialDjangoTutorial'])

Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> import django
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\Jarad\\PycharmProjects\\OfficialDjangoTutorial'
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Jarad\\PycharmProjects\\OfficialDjangoTutorial\mysite')
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.mysite.settings'
>>> django.setup()
>>> from mysite.polls.models import Question, Choice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jarad\PycharmProjects\OfficialDjangoTutorial\mysite\polls\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Jarad\PycharmProjects\OfficialDjangoTutorial\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 118, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class mysite.polls.models.Question doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'
```

**Restate my goal**: import the `Question` and `Choice` models in PyCharm's "Python Console" because the code hints and inspection of objects will better help me learn the methods and function parameters.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

[image: PyCharm Python Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your 'settings.py' file in your 'mysite' directory and add 'polls' to the list of installed apps like so:

```
    # Application definition
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'polls',
    ]
```

Since you are using pycharm, you can just go to the python console and import Questions and Choice using

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice
```

Comment: I kept `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` but it turns out `from polls.models import Question, Choice` fixed it (as opposed to `from mysite.polls.models import Question, Choice`. That tip from you helped! Thanks. Glad to have this figured out.